# Google Cloud VPS Compute Engine without a Domain

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a VPS with Google Cloud Compute Engine which I can reach through an external IP. Next to my external IP I can reach my VPS through: 122.xx.xx.34.bc.googleusercontent.com

Is Google also offering an option to reach your website through NAME.bc.googleusercontent.com or something different than an IP.

I don't want use cheap domain name or free domain name as .tk

Answer (score 0):

**You can use any domain name to reach your VM instance** that you run on Google Compute Engine. To do it follow steps below:

1. register domain name at any [domain name registrar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar)
2. set up DNS servers for your domain name (usually [DNS hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hosting_service) service provided by [domain name registrar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar))
3. [reserve external static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) for your VM (optional, but could be helpful)
4. [create A record](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/a-record/) that point to external IP of your VM
5. wait 24-72 hours for [propagating domain names](https://support.rocketspark.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010441768-What-is-Domain-Name-Propagation-)
6. reach you service via domain name like `https://domain.name`

In addition, you can register your domain name at [Google Domains](https://domains.google/) and use [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns) as DNS service for your domain.

You're not able to use `NAME.bc.googleusercontent.com` because `122.xx.xx.34.bc.googleusercontent.com` is a [PTR record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup).

Comment: This is not the answer I was searching for. Ofcourse I know I can use any domain and this was not my question. Cloud providers are usually using internal subdomains to reach your VPS through the subdomain instead of the IP, my question is how can I found out the subdomain in my google cloud vps.

Comment: Google Cloud doesn't provide such subdomains. As result, you can use external IP addresses or your own domain.

Comment: In addition, you can ask for such feature at Google Issue Tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187134&template=1162898